# Sencha Touch Application Scrolling & Ext.carousel.Carousel issue in Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-chrome, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on Sencha Touch 2.4 and Sencha Command 5.0.1.231.I'm Using Google Chrome to test my application. Recently i updated my Chrome Browser 39 to 43. Now My Sencha Touch Application getting stuck.

When i run my sencha touch application in Chrome 37 & 39 versions its working perfectly but not in version 43.

**Issue :**

1. **Scrollbar & Scrolling issue.**

   ```
        i can't scroll in my app and getting stuck.
   ```
2. **Ext.carousel.Carousel issue.**.

   ```
        I used carousel in app. but its getting stuck in 1st page. Can't swipe.
   ```

If i tried basic carousel code that also didn't work in my app.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
fullscreen: true,

defaults: {
    styleHtmlContent: true
},

items: [
    {
        html : 'Item 1',
        style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
    },
    {
        html : 'Item 2',
        style: 'background-color: #759E60'
    },
    {
        html : 'Item 3'
    }
]
```

});

i try to search regarding chrome browser updates and sencha touch interface issue but i couldn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this blog. This is due to chrome 43 bug

http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/chrome-43-breaks-sencha-touch-modern-toolkit-and-how-to-fix-it/#.VYopnJeqqko